# Bootstrap Modal Popup show content in ajax using EJS template

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I am working with node js and ejs(front end). How to show popup bootstrap modal using ajax call show content.

For example:
I display the table. Table have 2 columns (title, auction).
Once title clicked means need to show the all details in popup using Ajax API and ejs template.
I don't have idea for this. Can you please suggest what is the best way.
*Note - Lot of information I need to show in the popup. So I need to call AJAX api.

Comment: Have a modal div somewhere in your page. When you receive the data from your ajax call, load the content in your modal on success. Also to show/hide the modal, you can use $("<modal id/class").modal("show/hide");

Comment: I am using EJS template for frontend, so its not possible to load the content in id/class.